# OpenGL work with non-OpenGL drawings?

Tags: java, opengl

Can graphics rendered using OpenGL work with graphics rendered not using OpenGL?

I am starting to learn OpenGL, but I am still shy when it comes to actually coding everything in OpenGL, I feel more comfortable drawing them out with JPanel or Canvas. I'm assuming that it wouldn't cause much issue code wise, but displaying it all at the same time could cause issues? Or am I stuck with one or the other?

Comment: If you're not feeling comfortable using OpenGL then why use OpenGL in the first place? OpenGL is not a 3D engine. OpenGL is not a scene graph. OpenGL is a mere drawing library that puts points, lines or triangles to the screen. There's no scene in OpenGL, there are no models in OpenGL. So conceptually OpenGL is not very different from using a Canvas. The drawing tools are just a little bit more sophisticated (yet quite low level).

Answer (score 2):

Integrating OpenGL graphics with another non-OpenGL image or rendering boils down to compositing images.  You can take a 2D image and load it as a texture in OpenGL, such that you can then use that texture to paint a surface in OpenGL, or as is suggested by your question, paint a background.  Alternatively, you can use framebuffers in OpenGL to render an OpenGL scene to a texture, when can then be converted to a 2D bitmap and combined with another image.

There are limitations to this approach of course.  Once an OpenGL scene has been moved to a 2D image, generally you lose all depth (it's possible to preserve depth in an additional channel in the image if you want to do that, but it would involve additional work).

In addition, since presumably you want one image to not simply overwrite the other, you're going to have to include an alpha (transparency) channel in one of your images, so that when you combine them, areas which haven't been drawn will end up showing the underlying image.

However, I would suggest you undertake the effort to simply find one rendering API that serves all your needs.  The extra work you do to combine rendering output from two APIs is probably going to be wasted effort in the long run. It's one thing to embed an OpenGL control into an enclosing application that renders many of it's controls using a more conventional API like AWT.  On the other hand, it's highly unusual to try to composite output from both OpenGL and another rendering API into the same output area.

Perhaps if you could provide a more concrete example of what kinds of rendering you're talking about, people could offer more helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck with one or the other. You can't put them together.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to layer an OpenGL view and some other view on top of each other in one window.

Comment: How would you open the window?

Comment: Depends on what UI library is used. Maybe a JOGL canvas in a swing jframe for OGL, and a regular jframe on top of it.